# How can I pass in a function that sets a default image as a parameter to .attr() that is getting an image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to set the value of an image source.

In some cases the source will NOT return an image.
I want to call imgError() which sets the src to use a default image.

What is the syntax I can use to call this function together with .attr()?

Here is my code which sets the image source:

```
  $('#logo').attr("src",r.logoURL);
```

This is the function which is used for cases that r.logoURL is null:

```
 function imgError(image) {
   image.onerror = "";
   image.src = "/wwwroot/images/logo-mark.svg";
   return true;
    }
```

An example of another place where I am using this function

```
 <img src="' + item.profileImageURL + '"onerror="imgError(this);" 
  alt="Smiley face">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [logical OR operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

If `r.logoURL` is null it will use the default fallback

```
 $('#logo').attr("src", r.logoURL || "/wwwroot/images/logo-mark.svg" );
```